# Why is JS canvas showing up, but not updating?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas

I want to create a rectangle canvas that simply shows a few randomy generated particles. I have been messing around with canvas a bit off my project so I understand the basics. However, it seems when I try to integrate a canvas to my project, nothing is working.

The canvas HTML element is properly added to the DOM (I can see it thanks to the dashed border) and it is properly positioned.
I can also see the console message "Refreshed" which means the interval works.

BUT the canvas just remains blank, whatever I do. I've tried filling it, drawing circles, strokes and everything, and absolutely NOTHING shows up. It just remains a transparent rectangle.

Below is the (typscript) code that handles the canvas, and the method that calls the canvas:

```
    // particles canvas
    public static getTooltipParticlesCanvas(rarity: Data.Rarity, id: number) { 
        let posY = 25, posX = 25;
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = 232;
        canvas.height = 53;
        canvas.style.border = "1px dashed grey";
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.left = "0";

        clearInterval(this.particlesTooltipCanvasInterval);
        this.particlesTooltipCanvasInterval = setInterval(() => {
            // erase canvas
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            posY -= 0.25;
    
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 5, 5);
            console.log("Refreshed");
        }, 30);

        return canvas;
    }
    
    public static getWeaponTooltip(weapon: Weapon) {
        let str: string = '';
        // ...
        str += '<div class="canvasWrapper">' + this.getTooltipParticlesCanvas(weapon.rarity).outerHTML + '</div>
        // ...
        return str;
    }
```

The getWeaponTooltip returns a HTML string that is then appended via **.innerHTML** on a div.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OP says "The canvas HTML element is properly added to the DOM (I can see it thanks to the dashed border) and it is properly positioned."

Comment: @AKX very true. It would help to see a full working example in the question, OP

Comment: updated the post for more context. Now that I see it, maybe the **.outerHTML** thing is what's preventing the canvas from being updated...

Comment: @nitroxone Right. You absolutely can't use `.outerHTML` to put the canvas in place, since it won't be the same object your `canvas` variable refers to, or its `ctx`. You will need to refactor your code to work with actual HTML elements, not HTML strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in isolation (with references to `this` and the unused `rarity` and `id` removed), so the issue is in something you're not showing us.

```js
function getTooltipParticlesCanvas() { 
    let posY = 25, posX = 25;
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 232;
    canvas.height = 53;
    canvas.style.border = "1px dashed grey";
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.left = "0";
    setInterval(() => {
        // erase canvas
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        posY -= 0.25;

        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, 5, 5);
    }, 30);

    return canvas;
}

canvas = getTooltipParticlesCanvas();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: edited my question, added more context. Hope it's more clear.